# HttpContext.Session not maintaining state in .Net CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently I am working on .NET Core API 3.1 Application.
I have a requirement to maintain the state so that I can use it later.

Below are the code that I have done in startup.cs file.

Inside **ConfigureService** method

```
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                //options.Cookie.Name = "ephr";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

And the for **Configure** Method

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<HttpRequestBodyMiddleware>();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(allowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AS.ePHR.Business API V1");
            });
        }
```

**Set** the **session** value using below code

```
HttpContext.Session.Set<string>("OTP", _accountService.GenerateOTP(authenticatResponse.Id));
```

For **Get** value from **session** code is as bellow

```
var otpFromServer = HttpContext.Session.Get<string>("OTP");
```

**Problem:**

Able to set the value and after immediately when inspecting the session value then I can clearly see that value under session but in round trip from client when calling **GET** method to get the value from session then it returns null value because in list there is no "OTP" Session enlisted.

Can any one help me to understand why the same code is working for below 3.0 version but not in latest version..

Please find the below screen shot for more understanding and clarity

***While setting the values***
[image]

***While getting the value***
[image]

Comment: What is your client app? Mvc/SPA?

Comment: Angular version 10

Comment: Have you checked your client is actually also sending back the session cookie?

Comment: I did not can you help me with the steps to check the session cookie

Comment: Chrome has a dbugger F12 brings it up.  You want to check the network tab and this should capture what is being sent and received from/to server.  You may have to learn about some of this if you don't know it.  Lots of youtube videos etc on the subject of  inspecting requests.

Comment: Yes I know this debugger part.. let me check and will get back to yo u